# If there a delayscontenttouches equivalent on SwiftUI ScrollView?

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI, `Button`s highlight on touch.

But when you place one into a `ScrollView`, it will also highlight when the user scrolls.

On `UIKit`, the [delayscontenttouches](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619398-delayscontenttouches) UIScrollView's property exactly fixes this problem, but I haven't found a SwiftUI way to do it.

Here's some basic code that reproduces the problem.

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            print("1")
        }, label: {
            Color.blue.frame(height: 300)
        })
        Button(action: {
            print("2")
        }, label: {
            Color.blue.frame(height: 300)
        })
        Button(action: {
            print("3")
        }, label: {
            Color.blue.frame(height: 300)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a clean solution? The only ways I can see is either hacking with .gesture modifiers and manual delays, or going down UIViewRepresentable road.

Comment: Nope, but did not check if the new APIs fix the problem